# Mount problem on 12.10

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, mount

I've just done an online upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 - seemed to have gone well, but now I cannot access other drives (partitions) on my PC, also flash drives.

I get the following error:

```
Unable to mount location - Adding read ACL for uid 1000 to
media/malcolm failed: Operation not supported.
```

Content of mount -l:

```
/dev/sdb8 on / type ext2 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw) 
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755) 
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)    
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/malcolm/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=malcolm)
```

Here's some more system info

(fdisk)

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0 /dev/sdb8 / ext2 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation UUID=2bafe271-cb66-41ae-a4e4-831fa3b85fbe none swap sw 0 0 
# swap was on /dev/sdb9 during installation UUID=1f1e2de9-4983-4105-8a64-c8da5382ca2d none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Please put this information in your question, not in the comments, no one can read that!

Comment: I found an answer at <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1048059>

Answer (score 0):

Try creating/setting ownership on the path /media/malcolm

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/malcolm
sudo chown malcolm:malcolm /media/malcolm
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. Now its up to Canonical to kill the bug.